# Batch - Default Browser?

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way for using a batch file to find the default browser on my computer?

Comment: Which OS? Which version? If linux, which distro?

Comment: Isn't batch windows only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for a Windows .bat solution, this should work on Windows 2000 and later:

```
reg QUERY HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htmlfile\shell\open\command /ve
```

Result (on my Windows machine)

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htmlfile\shell\open\command
(Default)    REG_SZ    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -nohome
```

See the REG.EXE help for more information:

```
REG /?
```

Comment: This is not 100% correct, it will work in most cases (You probably want to check HTTP since .html could point to something other than htmlfile, "open" might not be the default verb etc)

Comment: @Anders: Sounds true enough, and in fact http was the first one I checked.  However, when I checked HTTP on my Windows 7 machine it pointed to Firefox whilst IE was my default browser.  Launching a url (http://google.com) opened IE, not Firefox.  FWIW, I liked your answer :-) +1.

Comment: @AnydE I noticed the same thing, but htmlfile always seems to point to iexplorer for me, regardless whether I set firefox or chrome as default.

Comment: That only associates it with `.html` files. What about `.htm` files? What about `.url` files? What about `http` addresses? This answer demonstrates the problem with doing things manually: it can be incomplete and you can miss a *lot*.

Answer (score 40):

Simply use

> start www.google.com

See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/iewebdevelopment/thread/5bf91e62-7be9-4f1d-9bac-5b2a4dd8ced7)

Comment: I have noticed that my answer has been receiving more votes lately however it may not answer the actual question of finding default browser. But it does answer how to open default browser using batch file. The distinction is subtle but important.

Comment: Sometimes the answers that answer a different question are the ones that most people come here looking for :)

Comment: I gave you an upvote because I believe in many cases this may be an xy question.  I was searching for how to load a webpage from the default browser and came across this question.

Comment: Also works for HTML files on the machine. For example I have a batch script that applies XSLT to an XML file and dumps it in `%TEMP%.\msxslout.html`. So, `start %TEMP%.\msxslout.html` opens it in my default web browser.

Comment: @p0lar_bear 's method for opening an html page only seems to work if its path and filename isn't quoted - so it can't include any spaces. However, it can be made to work by including an quoted extra empty string as the first parameter, e.g: `start "" "filename with spaces.html"`.

Comment: for the localhost, use `start http://localhost[:port]`, where port is optional - a plain `start localhost` fails to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to do this 100% correct in a batch file since the default command could come from a COM object and not a string in the registry ([MayChangeDefaultMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee453696(VS.85).aspx) will force IContextMenu to be called for double-clicks and could change the default action)

Here is some code that tries to do the right thing (The [fallback verb](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/30/2332224.aspx) is open, it really should be the first subkey, but I did not feel like dealing with that)

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set progid=htmlfile&set verb=open&set browsercmd=
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=_" %%a IN ('2^>nul REG QUERY "HKCR\.html" /ve^|find /V ""^|find /V "HKEY_"') DO FOR /F "tokens=1,*" %%b IN ("%%~a") DO if not "%%~c"=="" set progid=%%~c
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=_" %%a IN ('2^>nul REG QUERY "HKCR\%progid%\shell" /ve^|find /V ""^|find /V "HKEY_"') DO FOR /F "tokens=1,*" %%b IN ("%%~a") DO if not "%%~c"=="" set verb=%%~c
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=_" %%a IN ('2^>nul REG QUERY "HKCR\%progid%\shell\%verb%\command" /ve^|find /V ""^|find /V "HKEY_"') DO FOR /F "tokens=1,*" %%b IN ("%%~a") DO if not "%%~c"=="" set browsercmd=%%c

echo.DefaultBrowser=%browsercmd%
```

This code probably has problems, but at least it tries to find the correct verb. You also have to deal with the fact that the returned string could contain "%1".

If all you really want to do is open a URL, all you need is `start http://example.com`
If you want to open the browser, but not a specific URL, a ugly hack like `start "" http://about:blank` might just work.

Comment: Yes, it does have problems, the same ones as Andy’s. See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684849/batch-default-browser#comment30577333_3684922) to his answer to see them.

Comment: @Synetech The default browser for .url might not be the same as for http etc but that kind of configuration is very uncommon and in those cases there is not really a default browser, there are multiple, so there is no 100% correct answer (Unless you are asking about a specific type, my example had to pick one and used .html). No program should really care what the default is, it should just use ShellExecute/start and let Windows deal with it. Wanting to do this in a batch file of course just makes things even more complicated...

Comment: Exactly, the very concept of a “default browser” is faulty. I just [explained why](http://superuser.com/a/686007/3279) today.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps someone. I needed to start the default browser with a html file.

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem setup a default browser in case we fail
set default_browser=C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe

rem look in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htmlfile\shell\open\command registry for the default browser
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('REG QUERY HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htmlfile\shell\open\command /ve ^| FIND /i "default"') do (
   set input=%%a
)
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

rem parse the input field looking for the second token
for /f tokens^=^2^ eol^=^"^ delims^=^" %%a in ("!input!") do set browser=%%a

setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

rem this may not be needed, check if reg returned a real file, if not unset browser
if not "%browser%" == "" if not exist "%browser%" set browser=
if "%browser%"=="" set browser=%default_browser%
"%browser%" index.html
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will set the Environment variable `browser` to `FirefoxURL` which gives you a good indicator:

```
@ECHO OFF
REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice > browser.txt
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=*" %%G IN (browser.txt) DO ( SET browser=%%G )
SET browser=%browser:~20%
ECHO Is: %browser%
```

It works by querying the registry to a text file then skipping the first two lines (useless for your purposes), then taking the text that starts at the 20th character of te remaining line. Which gives you `FirefoxURL`

Answer (score 1):

Andy E's answer does not seem to work for me, it opens IE instead of Chrome.
But, if I use http instead of htmlfile it does. Like this.

```
reg QUERY HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command /ve
```

Comment: What about `.html` files? What about `.htm` files? What about `.url` bookmarks? And so on?

Answer (score 1):

bubble's answer has some caveats.

### This is what works in much more cases for me:

```
start "" explorer "protocol://your.complicated/url?foo=bar"
```

The only thing you have to escape is a double quote, and you escape it by typing it once more.

Works at least for protocols `http://`, `https://` and `file://` (without query string). Doesn't work for `ftp://` URLs (it opens them as a network drive).

---

### Fail cases of the accepted answer

First, the webpage has to start with `www.`

```
rem Works
start www.google.com

rem FAILS!
start google.com
The system cannot find the file google.com

rem FAILS!
start translate.google.com
The system cannot find the file translate.google.com
```

This can be fixed by prepending `http://`

```
rem Works
start http://google.com

rem Works even for file:// protocol
start file://C:/test/main.html

rem Works - you can even pass QSA
start http://google.com?foo=bar

rem FAILS! outch, you have to escape ampersands
start http://google.com?foo=bar&baz=baz
'baz' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

rem FAILS! but QSA only works for http/s URLs; for file:// protocol, it is ignored
start file://D:/Programování/lumix-link/Control.html?foo=bar
rem opens file://D:/Programování/lumix-link/Control.html
```

One might e.g. think of enclosing the webpage in double quotes (to avoid misinterpretation of some characters). Then it fails and instead tries to open another CMD.exe with the given string as name:

```
rem FAILS!
start "http://google.com"
```

Okay, this is not a bug, just a mislead. This is the expected behavior. Let's fix it:

```
rem Works
start "" "http://google.com"

rem FAILS!
start "" "google.com"
The system cannot find the file google.com.
```

So we really have to provide an executable that should be launched. You can see the super-long answers here that succeed better or worse in getting the path to the default browser. But what's much simpler and bullet-proof is to use `explorer` to launch the webpage. But since explorer decides on what app to launch based on the protocol, you have to use the protocol prefix. And that's it!

```
rem FAILS!
rem start "" explorer "google.com"

rem Works
rem start "" explorer "http://google.com"

rem Works
rem start "" explorer "http://google.com?foo=bar"

rem FAILS! QSA still not supported on file:// URLs
rem start "" explorer "file://C:/test/main.html?foo=bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, @Rob.

@Rob's answer is close, but it still only pulls the ProgId. This one will set the browser name as reported by the ProgId (not always what you expect) in the `browser` variable, the specific `verb` used as `browserverb`, and the cmd path as `browsercmd`:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
:: parse the ProgId
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,* delims==" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice" /v ProgId 2^>NUL ^| more +2`) DO (
    SET browserstub=%%C
    :: parse for Class information
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,* delims==" %%R IN (`REG QUERY "HKCR\!browserstub!" /v AppUserModelId 2^>NUL`) DO SET "browser=%%T"
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,* delims==" %%R IN (`REG QUERY "HKCR\!browserstub!\shell" /ve 2^>NUL`) DO SET "browserverb=%%T"
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,* delims==" %%R IN (`REG QUERY "HKCR\!browserstub!\shell\!browserverb!\command" /ve 2^>NUL`) DO SET "browsercmd=%%T"
)
:: display results
SET browser
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the method i am using to open a browser window

```
start /REALTIME "~\iexplore.exe" "http://192.168.0.1"
```

Which opens internet explorer at the logon screen of the router, i have tested it on win 7 and win 10 and it works well. What i have gotten from this forum is that opening any website from a batch file or cmd window will use the default browser.

which works well here on win 10

```
start /REALTIME "" "http://192.168.0.1"
```

This also works well.

```
start /ABOVENORMAL /SEPARATE "" "http://192.168.0.1"
```

which allows the browser priority over other apps using cpu and also runs in a separate memory space which i have found to cause a lot of work for intruders of sorts.

The empty (path) "" need to be there other wise it just opens another cmd window.