# Launch default Windows browser without URL from .bat/.vbs?

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, registry

I need to be able to launch the default Windows browser, **without specifying** a URL (**should open to home page**).

The solution should preferably not require compiling a binary (so a .bat, .vbs, or the like).

It should also work on Win7+ through Win10 without installing any software, and without admin rights.

I have seen solutions that specify a URL, but that will not work for me.  Is this possible ?
Thanks !

The answer [Batch - Default Browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684849/batch-default-browser) is not a duplicate because that answer gives you the default application to open html files, not the default browser for URL handling.

Comment: Take a look at this [Batch - Default Browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684849/batch-default-browser)

Comment: @Hackoo no solution there works.  it reports IE no matter what.

Comment: @IsaacHanson in which case IE is set as the default for opening HTML, doesn't mean the linked answer is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch - Default Browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684849/batch-default-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is only a part answer, it looks only at the current user registry and echoes the response accordingly. *(Remove `Echo=` from line 12 then delete line 6 to actually attempt to open the browser)*.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "RK1=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations"
Set "RK1=%RK1%\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice"
Set "RK2=HKCU\Software\Classes\%%B\shell\open\command"
Call :Sub
Timeout -1
GoTo :EOF

:Sub    
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('Reg Query "%RK1%" /V Progid 2^>Nul') Do (
    For /F "Tokens=2*" %%C In ('Reg Query "%RK2%" /VE 2^>Nul') Do (
        For %%E In (%%D) Do If Exist "%%~E" Echo=Start "" "%%~E"))
GoTo :EOF
```

It is only a part answer because if the current user hasn't changed their default browser that key/data may not exist. *(At that point the checks would become more involved).*

Comment: This particular script fails to do anything, but it puts me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with help from @Compo

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim strProgId
strProgId = oShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice\ProgID")
Dim strExe
strExe = oShell.RegRead("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\" & strProgId & "\shell\open\command\")
wscript.echo strExe
```

Comment: Just bear in mind that `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is mapped as `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes`. My example used `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` because it was looking at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` for the other data. I would suggest that you should at least check `HKCU` first and if not there look at the `HKLM` key.

Comment: `for /f tokens^=^2^ eol^=^"^ delims^=^"` to parse by double quote characters never seen that particular syntax

Comment: Registry subkeys HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations* were added in for Win 7 and higher I assume. @Isaac Hanson are you sure that "ProgID" key is always exists on a machine?